# How do I stop windbg from being the interactive debugger?

Tags: windbg

What is the proper way to undo *windbg -I* on vista/win7?

Is it as simple as deleting the registry keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to delete the entire registry key.  Deleting the Debugger value is enough.

When an exception occurs, the system first looks to see if there is a debugger registered.  If so, it just launches the command line specified.  Otherwise, it invokes Windows Error Reporting to collect the crash dump.  All Windbg -I does is change the registered debugger value in the AeDebug key.

Comment: On 64-bit versions of Windows, you should also delete the Debugger value under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug