# Debuggers don't kick in when application crashes

Tags: windbg

I am trying to debug an application with Immunity debugger. I also tried WinDbg. I have set them as default JIT debugger through the Registry but it doesn`t work.

I tried in Windows XP SP3 and in Windows 7 but it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457570/windows-does-not-produce-full-crash-dumps-even-though-registry-is-set-correctly/30469083#30469083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [install Windbg as the default postmortem debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561306.aspx) by running this from the command line:

```
windbg -IS
```

From then on, the next time an application crashes Windbg will appear, attached to the process.

To undo this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014345/1698557).

If this doesn't work, you'll need to add more details to your question.

Comment: It was my failure. The application did not crash but I thought that it crashed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This might help someone whose immunity debugger does not kick in when the application really crashes like mine.

In regedit, edit the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug

```
Default: (value not set)
Auto: 1
Debugger: "C:\Program Files\Immunity Inc\Immunity Debugger\ImmunityDebugger.exe" -p %ld
UserDebuggerHotKey: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Immunity Debugger, you may want to try to install python 2.7 on your PC.
If it is already installed try reinstalling it